# Activar conexiones TCP/IP postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, tcpip

Saludos tengo el siguiente problema tengo un servidor en la nube donde tengo alojado mi base de datos en postgresql. A través mi aplicativo en JAVA puedo acceder a mis base de datos desde cualquier punto con Internet.

Estoy haciendo un aplicativo en php con la conexion a la misma base de datos cuando corro el xampp y ejecuto en localhost puedo acceder a mi base de datos pero cuando lo subo a mi hosting me lanza el siguiente error

```
 psql -h 107.170.158.89 -U postgres
 psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "107.170.158.89" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

con JAVA funciona, con php de forma local tambien funciona pero desde mi hosting no funciona

mi pg_hba esta configurado de la sgt manera

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

esta tambien activado en postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

no se que pueda estar pasando mi servidor de base de datos esta en centos

Comment: Una mejor idea es que tengas una web API y que tu aplicación de escritorio se conecte a ella y que esta API se contecte a tu base de datos. El motivo es aumentar la seguridad. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Cambia la linea:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
 host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

por:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             all               md5
```

Con lo anterior le estas indicando que que las conexiones serán por la interfaz 0.0.0.0 
Y prueba bajando el `firewall`, no es buena practica pero veremos si funciona ya luego solo es de configurar

Comment: Hola Igmer gracias por responder hice la prueba pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado esta es es la linea de codigo del PHP con el que hago la conexion

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=107.170.158.89 port=5432 dbname=bd_daos user=postgres password=xxxxx")
    or die('No se ha podido conectar: ' . pg_last_error());

Comment: systemctl restart hhttpd y systemctl restart postgresql y orueba sin ponre el puerto ya que ese es por defecto

Comment: en mi servidor de la base de datos no tengo el serivicio de httpd .. sera por eso? el servidor de base de datos solo lo uso para ese fin .. por otro lado tengo un hosting en donde estoy alojando el aplicativo en PHP el problema surge para conectar estos dos servicios hice la prueba sin el puerto y me da el mismo erro

Comment: me referia a reiniciar apache en  centos creo que es httpd... ah ya se prueba bajando el firewall... systemclt stop firewalld

Comment: has ping 107.170.158.89

Comment: hice ping (mi servidor de base de datos es 200.60.112.170) siempre me sale 
Estadísticas de ping para 200.60.112.170:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 3, perdidos = 1
    (25% perdidos)
lo intente en 3 ocaciones y lo mismo
el estado de firewall me sale desactivo

Comment: tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
 revisa el log del servidor de base de datos

Comment: y si es el 200.60.112.170 porque quieres hacer psql al 107.170.158.89

Comment: en la pregunta y los comentarios puse datos referenciales... busque en los log no encontre esa ruta q me pusiste pero encontre esto -> Aug 22 10:16:34 server lfd[3911]: *SSH login* from 190.234.119.73 into the root account using password authentication en el archivo lfd

Comment: no pero no nos dice nada eso es extraño deberia funcionar ya, solo viendo los log de postgres podriamos entender que pasa

Comment: si tmb me parece extraño pero al parecer es un bloqueo de mi servidor de base de datos encontre tmb este log -> Aug 22 10:27:44 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:23:53:71:90:6c:ac:82:a4:e1:08:00 .....

Comment: ah si es lo que te decia que probaras bajand el firewall con comando systemctl stop firewalld o el que se adapte a tu sistema, si eso te deja pasar quiere decir es que es un problema de configuracion del firewall

Comment: Estimado Igmer muchas gracias por la ayuda.. tal como dijiste era un problema de firewall ya tengo acceso despues de hacer varias pruebas.

Comment: bueno me alegro por ti