# ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser el detalle?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

```
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: no hay una
linea en pg_hba.confg para «::1», usuario «postgres», base de datos «postgres»,
cifrado SSL connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: 
FATAL: no hay una línea en pg_hba.confg para «::1», usuario «postgres»,
base de datos «postgres», sin cifrado
```

Error al conectar, al momento de introducir contraseña en pgadmin

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para colocar el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_. Además, pon cuál es el problema en cuestión en el título de la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Dónde está instalado el pgadmin y dónde está corriendo la BD postgresql? Si estás intentando localhost todo, mira que estás intentando IPv6 y es posible que la configuración por defecto no funcione. Prueba con 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Guíate también por https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190526/activar-conexiones-tcp-ip-postgresql